# Should door jamb be lifted off subfloor or touching?

Tags: doors

Simple question:  when installing a custom made door jamb, should it be sitting directly on top of the subfloor or be lifted up a little (like drywall is lifted 1/2", for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave it a little off if you want = about 1/4"... You will be cutting the bottoms when install flooring.  If you do carpet a 1/4" is about perfect.

Comment: for hardwood or tile I like it cut flush with the finished floor surface.